# 'null' getting appended at the end of URL on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, url, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request, however, a null character is appended at the end of the URL resulting in a 404 error.
It happens even when I use fetch instead of axios

```
axios.get(
      `/api/v1/sites/${site_id}/configs`,
      {
        headers: defaultOpts.headers
      }
    )
```

In the browser console it looks correct, however, on server it goes like this
`/api/v1/sites/635144/configsnull`

I was able to fix it by either sending some search params or adding a '?' at the end of the URL

```
axios.get(
      `/api/v1/sites/${site_id}/configs?`,
      {
        headers: defaultOpts.headers
      }
    )
```

How can I fix it by not adding a question mark or mandating search params?

[image: API call][image: Error Info]

Comment: Can you post what is in `defaultOpts.headers`? This is a very interesting problem.

Comment: ```headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
  },```

Comment: Could you please show some screenshots from your browser's _Network_ console showing the GET request? **Where** exactly are you seeing `configsnull`?

Comment: Images added in the problem description.

Comment: Seems like there it is expecting some param which you explicitly need to set empty when not putting  '?'.. this problem appears to be arising due to parameter sequencing of `axios.get`

Comment: Found the solution, after Node upgrade one of the plugin was returning search params as null instead of empty string. This resulted in 'null' being appended to the URL. A simple check solved the issue.